# How to tell what row of a table a step is operating on in Cucumber-JVM?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am trying to get the current row count processed in "Examples" under "Scenario Outline" . How can I get the current row count in the step definition? I don't want to pass a number in the Examples. Is there any way?

```
Scenario Outline:
    When the name is entered as "<fruit>" <days>

Examples:
    |fruit|days|
    |Apple|10|
    |Orange|12|
    |Guava|3|
    ...
```

In the step definition, I want to get the row processed as 1,2,3,...(in place of XXXXX).

```
@When("^the name is entered as \"([^\"]*)\" ([^\"]*)$")
public void the_name_is_entered_as(String fruitName, int days) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Current Row processsed is: "+XXXXXXX)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it that I can think of (which is not very pretty) is to count the rows behind the scenes yourself:

```
private static int rowIndex = 0;

@When("^I enter the name as \"([^\"]+)\"$")
public void i_enter_the_name_as(String fruit) {
    rowIndex++;
    // now you can use it in this and subsequent steps
}
```

This will only work if "I enter the name as" is only used in a single scenario outline. If you wanted to use it in more than one scenario outline the best thing I can think of is to reset the counter in a different scenario.

Comment: For each scenario row from the examples table cucumber or any DI framework will initialize a new step definition class, so it will always show 1. Try putting in static for rowIndex. You can also get the scenario object into a Before hook and have a look at the scenario.getId() method. I am not sure but it returns an integer with the row number.

Comment: scenario.getId() returns the following string feature-description : scenariooutline-description : example-description : rownumber + 1.

Comment: Yes, was supposed to be static. Not sure why I took that out. @Grasshopper that other one sounds like another answer.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Yeah you are right. Will add as answer. Just it seemed a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Scenario scenario;

@Before
public void before(Scenario sce) {
    this.scenario = sce;
    System.out.println("SCENARIO ID -- " +scenario.getId());
}
```

You will get a string like for scenario outline -  feature-description ; scenariooutline-description ; example-description ; rownumber + 1.

For a simple scenario you will get - feature-description ; scenario-description.

For scenario outline case you can split with delimiter ";" and use the last part after subtracting 1.

It is a bit of a hack which depends on the scenario id string remaining in this pattern.